# When does a Portable Class Library reference mscorlib, Version 5.0.5.0?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, portable-class-library

I have been trying to figure out the combination of platforms which when selected, causes a Portable Class Library to reference `mscorlib, Version 5.0.5.0`.

**I tried many combinations including Silverlight 5.0**, but my PCL always referenced 2.0.5.0

Further, there is no `mscorlib, Version 5.0.5.0` in any my Reference Assemblies....\ProfileXYZ folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no combination of platforms that would get you a Portable Class Library with a reference to mscorlib version 5.0.5.0.  I think that reference would mean the library was compiled for Silverlight 5.